# When I invoke a JFrame and a process Callable from another JFrame, freezes the GUI

Tags: swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread, callable

I have two jframes: WinA and WinB, also i have a class Callable to do a process.

WinA have a button to do a process in thread with Callable and show a WinB witha a progressbar.

`WinA` class code - ActionPerformed of button.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            WinA wa = new WinA();
            WinB wb = new WinB();
             ClaseCallable callbd = new ClaseCallable();
             ExecutorService exesrv = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
             Future sresp;
             sresp = exesrv.submit(callbd);
             wb.getProgressbar().setIndeterminate(true);
             wb.setVisible(true);
             System.out.println(">>" + sresp.get());
             exesrv.shutdown();
             wb.setVisible(false);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WinA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

`ClaseCallable`class code

```
public class ClaseCallable implements Callable<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Thread.sleep(250);
        }
        return 33;
    }

}
```

When I run from `WinA` and pressed the button opens the `WinB`, but the window is white, at the end shows the result.

Do not understand why this happens, if it is performing and swing events in EDT thread and process in another thread.

Comment: Your WinB ought to be a JDialog.  I see your action code being performed on the same thread as the Swing components.

Comment: Also I tried it with a JDialog. How should it do it? ... it is supposed that Callable is executed in another thread      @GilbertLeBlanc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `future.get()` which will block until the task completes:

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()

> get V get()
>         throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
>
> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Comment: But I can't see the progress of the task, or if it's indeterminated view the progressbar with the indeterminated... If with it's don't work, I don't know how do it...@JohnGardner

Comment: could you use `future.get(timeout,unit)` with a small timeout in a loop until it returns a result?  otherwise, you'll have to look at other examples of how to correctly use future from a ui thread.